# how do I get the keyboard height prior to it needing to be shown

Tags: ios, uikeyboard

I'm structuring a view around the height of the keyboard. I don't want to have to wait asynchronously for my textfield to begin editing and scraping the keyboard NSNotification and then resizing my view.

**Is it possible to ask the system for its keyboard height prior to it appearing**?

Thankyou!

Comment: Use the `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` notification.

Comment: Thats still after becomeFirstResponder can be called.

Comment: Also remember, that the keyboard will always report its height as if it were in portrait, so when in landscape orientation you should get its width.

Comment: @Losiowaty No, do not do that. There is a proper way to convert the provided frame to get the proper value.

Comment: @MikeS One thing to consider is that the keyboard height could be different for each text field if the text field has a custom `inputView`.

Comment: @rmaddy Could you provide a link? I thought that this was not the best way to achieve this and would be happy to learn it :)

Comment: @rmaddy yeah I guess I'm assuming since I'm working with only my UText controls that I know there are no input views. This could change with the new ios8 custom keyboards probably so I think you're right. There is no way to get it prior to the keyboard appearing for a good reason. If you say an answer to that effect, mentioning that the uikeyboardwillshownotification is as close as they will let me get, then I will accept your answer. If you can't be bothered I'll just vote to close the question :).